# POST via OVCHTTPSessionManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, post

How to make POST request with body via OVCHTTPSessionManager?
I didn't find any except

```
[self rac_POST:@"name"
               parameters:parameters];
```

method.

There's one

```
[self rac_POST:@"name" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {
            NSData *dataOnObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:order];
            [formData appendPartWithHeaders:nil
                                       body:dataOnObject];
        }];
```

But i can't figure out how it works